# Can I get cookies from Safari in a SFSafariViewController?

Tags: ios, cookies, safari, openid-connect, sfsafariviewcontroller

tl;dr; see the question below

In my app, I have a login that uses SFSafariViewController and ASWebAuthenticationSession that follows the OAuth 2.0 flow (Using the AppAuth library).

The login works and the cookies are shared with Safari as expected. Thanks to the cookie sharing, users are automatically logged-in if they use the Safari app.

However, back in the app, if I launch a SFSafariViewController again, the cookies are missing. This surprises me, because I thought the cookie Store is the same for SFSafariViewController and Safari, and it clearly worked in the direction from SFSafariVC to the Safari app during login.
**Is it intended not to work the other way round - from Safari to SFSafariViewController, or is it a bug?**

I have not found clear statements in the documentation.
Of course I have not set ephemeral session to true, but according to the documentation it would do the opposite of what I want to achieve:

> [When not using an ephemeral session, all cookies except session cookies are available to the browser.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/authenticating_a_user_through_a_web_service)

I've also found somehow related radars like http://www.openradar.me/33323462 and http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5036182937272320 or this stackoverflow post: [Why is SFSafariWebViewController not sharing cookies with Safari properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36203617/why-is-sfsafariwebviewcontroller-not-sharing-cookies-with-safari-properly#comment79596359_38666919) but they do not answer my question.

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38666919) it could work if the cookies have an expiry date (set to a future date). I verified the cookies - they all have a future expiry date.

**My question: Am I doing something wrong, or is this expected behaviour, that SFSafariViewController does not get cookies from an earlier SFSafariViewController instance in the same app or from Safari?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**REQUIREMENTS**

So it seems you want a solution to invoke secured web content from a mobile app, and to avoid an extra login. It is a common requirement and I will be adding some stuff to [my blog](https://authguidance.com/2020/06/17/mobile-web-integration-goals/) on this topic over the next month or so.

**STATE OF THE INDUSTRY**

The problem with the above is that third party cookies, such as those issued by Identity Providers, are often dropped by default these days due to browser security initiatives such as [Intelligent Tracking Prevention](https://www.theverge.com/2020/3/24/21192830/apple-safari-intelligent-tracking-privacy-full-third-party-cookie-blocking) changes - which is ON by default in Safari:

[image]

**COOKIE PROPERTIES**

Worth checking that your cookies are issued with SameSite=None, which will give you the best options for a third party cookie based solution.

**MOBILE FIRST DESIGNS**

In an OAuth world, in order to meet the requirements, it is likely to be necessary to send a token from the mobile UI to the web UI, which of course has prerequisites that need to be designed for:

- Web UI must use tokens
- Web UI must use different strategies for token handling depending on the host

**OPTION 1**

One option is to use a mobile web view to show the web content - see my code below:

- [Web UI Code to ask the host for tokens](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/mobile/mobileAuthenticator.ts)
- [Mobile UI Code to service these requests](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobileweb.ios/blob/master/Source/Plumbing/Interop/CustomWebView.swift)

**OPTION 2**

Another option is to send something representing the token in a query string parameter from the mobile app to the Web UI, in which case you need to ensure that:

- No usable tokens are recorded in web server logs
- The token has a one time use only

A typical implementation would look like this:

- Mobile UI calls an /api/token/encrypt endpoint
- API stores a token hash in a database and returns an encrypted value with a short time to live
- Token is sent from the Mobile App to the Web UI
- Web UI calls an /api/token/decrypt endpoint to get the real token
- The API's decrypt implementation deletes the database entry

Comment: Hi @gary-archer, thank you for your response - much appreciated. Your blogpost is also very nice. Given all the information I got, I get the impression that it is not possible by design above iOS12. As far as I understand is that the ASWebAuthenticationSession is only for the login flow, I can't use it afterwards if I'm already logged in. The only option I have is to open either Safari (that works) or SFSafariViewController (doesn't fit my needs because of missing cookies). Of course I can use the access token to make requests to my secure backend API, but for SFSafariVC I would need cookies.

Comment: So do you have 2 apps? A web app and a mobile app? And you're trying to invoke a secured web view from the mobile app?

Comment: I have a native iOS app, and a web-application. The iOS app, for a certain feature, has to use parts of the web-application. Preferably inside a SFSafariViewController, in order to keep the user (visually) inside the iOS app. So, yes, I try to invoke a secured web view from the mobile app. (Of course WKWebView is not possible because it has it's own cookie store).

Comment: Will update my original answer later - you have some problems with cross domain cookies and mobile / web integration. Answer will be based around sending a token from the mobile app to the web UI.

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer. SameSite=None does already apply for all cookies. I already did Option1 in (another) project to share the accessToken with the webapp. This time, this is unfortunately not an option. Thank you for your comprehensive answer! In my opinion, there are only two options (the one's you explained), as SFSafariWebView does not share cookies   in this direction.